# Can not add apt repository cloud-archive:antelope of openstack in kubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, openstack, cloud

I run

```
sudo add-apt-repository cloud-archive:antelope
```

I get this error

```
Repository: 'deb http://ubuntu-cloud.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/antelope main'
Description:
Ubuntu Cloud Archive for OpenStack Antelope
More info: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/OpenStack/CloudArchive
Adding repository.
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel.
Found existing deb entry in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cloudarchive-antelope.list
Adding deb entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cloudarchive-antelope.list
Found existing deb-src entry in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cloudarchive-antelope.list
Adding disabled deb-src entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cloudarchive-antelope.list
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ubuntu-cloud-keyring
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 364, in <module>
    sys.exit(0 if addaptrepo.main() else 1)
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 357, in main
    shortcut.add()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/shortcuthandler.py", line 222, in add
    self.add_key()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/cloudarchive.py", line 124, in add_key
    subprocess.run(f'apt-get install -y {UCA_KEYRING_PACKAGE}'.split(), check=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 524, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['apt-get', 'install', '-y', 'ubuntu-cloud-keyring']' returned non-zero exit status 100.
```

Have I miss something else? My distro linux is kubuntu 22.04